# Set active quads doesn't work as expected

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, distort

I have this shape I made, and the UV is a bit distorted.
[image]

I want to make it flat. But when I select all the faces and click on "set active quads" it causes some unexpected issues, and I'm not really sure why, or how can I fix it.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). It sometimes helps to reset the UV, before you unwrap with active quads.

Comment: I tried reset and then set active quads, still doesn't work.